# Table of the 201 indexing components as defined in the 2009 spec?

Tags: radicals

Is there a free online table of the 201 indexing components defined in GF 0011-2009, a table that includes for each item

- details of how to write it, including order and direction of strokes;
- canonical ordinal (similar to "Radical 75" etc. for the Kangxi radicals); and an
- associated English word for each item?